"The kernel appears to have died" error in Jupyter while using pyarrow
Here is the code:
bad_array = pa.array([5.25,5.11,7.1,3.111,-1.2])
good_array = pa.array([5.25,5.11,7.1,3.111,2.4])

array = bad_array

boolean_mask = pc.less(array, pa.scalar(0))

boolean_mask.true_count

In attempting to return the "true_count" of the boolean array, the kernel dies.  The "false_count" works fine, however.  Very strange.
I previously assumed the problem was due to the size of the data I was attempting to process, but then I tried to run a test on these very small arrays and had the same error.

What version of PyArrow are you using? There was a bug that could cause a crash in PyArrow 15 and earlier that's been fixed in 16, see https://github.com/apache/arrow/issues/41016. If you're not on 16, could you try upgrading?

pyarrow 15.0.1.  i will update and report back

you were right.  i upgraded to pyarrow 16.0.0 and it worked.  thanks!

Great. I added a top-level answer which you can accept.

This is due to a known bug which has been reported at https://github.com/apache/arrow/issues/41016. It's been fixed in PyArrow 16.0.0 so upgrading to PyArrow 16.0.0 or newer should fix your issue.
